# mwaitx instruction not blocking

Tags: c++, assembly, x86-64, amd-processor

According to AMD's official docs, the `mwaitx` instruction can be used with the `monitorx` instruction to monitor an address range and see if it is modified. My code seems to be returning immediately, seemingly doing nothing.

The code in question:

```
push rbx
push r9
mov r9, rcx ;save parameter for later
mov eax, 80000001h ;check cpuid flag for monitorx, which is required regardless of whether or not we look at it
cpuid
mov rax, r9 ;the address to monitor
xor rcx, rcx ;no extensions
xor rdx, rdx ;no hints
monitorx rax, rcx, rdx
xor rax, rax ;no hints
mov rcx, 10b ;timeout specified in rbx, no interrupts
xor rbx, rbx ;infinite timeout
mwaitx rax, rcx, rbx ;not waiting; passes immediately
pop r9
pop rbx
ret
```

The C++ code:

```cpp
int main()
{
    void* data = VirtualAlloc(nullptr, size, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READONLY);
    //int x = 5;
    std::cout << data << '\n';
    monitorAddress(data);
    std::cout << data << '\n';

    VirtualFree(data, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation in AMD's manual ([vol 3, rev 3.33](https://www.amd.com/system/files/TechDocs/24594.pdf)) does *not* say that `ECX[0]` = 0 will mask interrupts even if IF=1 in E/RFLAGS.  It would be insane for user-space to be able to do that without having IO privilege level = 0 (which would allow you to run a `cli` instruction), and the wording doesn't really hint at it.

In user-space, there should be no way to get a CPU stuck in a way that would make it hard for the kernel to wake it up!  If you want to go for longer before asking the OS to put this thread to sleep (e.g. with Linux `futex` to wake you back up on memory change), you could use it in a loop exactly like a spin-wait loop that uses `pause` or something.  From the OS's perspective it'd be the same: this thread is occupying the CPU for the entire time.

**It's likely that your code does actually arm the monitor and enter the optimized sleep state, but wakes on the next timer interrupt after at most a few milliseconds.**  Check with `rdtsc` to see how long it sleeps for, because human perception of screen output can't distinguish that from failing to sleep at all.

What the documentation actually *does* say about the supported extension flags in ECX:

> Bit 0: When set, allows interrupts to wake MWAITX, even when eFLAGS.IF = 0. Support for this
> extension is indicated by a feature flag returned by the CPUID instruction.

So, as an extension, you can override the fact that interrupts are disabled in eFLAGS, to make sure you don't enter a sleep state that lasts until an NMI.  Otherwise, with `ECX[0]` = 0, all previous stuff in the documentation applies, including:

> Events that cause an exit from the monitor event pending state include:
>
> - A store from another processor matches the address range established by the MONITORX
>   instruction.
> - The timer expires.
> - **Any unmasked interrupt**, including INTR, NMI, SMI, INIT.
> - RESET.
> - Any far control transfer that occurs between the MONITORX and the MWAITX.

If you actually *did* want to do put the CPU into a sleep that wouldn't be ended by pending interrupts, you'd use `cli` before `monitorx` / `mwaitx`.  Or use traditional `monitor` / `mwait` if you're in kernel mode proper, rather than user-space after a Linux `iopl()` system call or other way of getting IOPL=0 with CPL=3 (current privilege level), so you can't run privileged instructions in general, only the specific ones allowed by the IO privilege level, like in/out / cli/sti.

Unfortunately:

> There is no indication after exiting MWAITX of why the processor exited or if the timer expired. It is
> up to software to check whether the awaiting store has occurred, and if not, determining how much
> time has elapsed if it wants to re-establish the MONITORX with a new timer value.

BTW, if you don't want the timer to be a possible exit condition, you can just leave `ECX[1]` = 0

> Bit 1: When set, EBX contains the maximum wait time expressed in Software P0 clocks, the same
> clocks counted by the TSC. **Setting bit 1 but passing in a value of zero on EBX is equivalent to
> setting bit 1 to a zero. The timer will not be an exit condition.**

And BTW, EAX=0 isn't "no hints"; EAX[7:4] is always the desired C-state level, encoded at C-state - 1.  So EAX=0 hints that you want C1 state.  (To hint that you want C0 state, a less deep sleep that's faster to wake from, you'd set EAX = 0xf0, because F + 1 = 0.)

---

It's also pointless to do `xor rax,rax` instead of `xor eax,eax`; writing a 32-bit register implicitly zeroes the upper bits of the full 64-bit register, so there's no false dependency.  And there's no need to tempt the assembler into wasting a REX prefix to actually encode it as written.  The MWAITX implicit input registers are all 32-bit anyway, so `xor ecx, ecx` would also be appropriate.

Also, r9 is call-clobbered (aka volatile) in the Windows x64 calling convention; you can just use it without saving/restoring, along with r8..r11.

And no you don't have to run a `cpuid` every time you want to do `monitorx` / `mwaitx`!  AMD's documentation says you need to check once per program / library init, but there's no way the CPU can actually enforce that.  It's not going to track across context switches which user-space process has actually run a CPUID.

```
;; uint32_t waitx(void *p)
;; returns TSC ticks actually slept for
waitx:
    mov   rax, rcx    ;the address to monitor
    xor   ecx, ecx    ;no extensions
    xor   edx, edx    ;no hints
    monitorx rax, ecx, edx    ; or just monitorx if your assembler complains

    lfence
    rdtsc
    lfence            ; make sure we're done reading the clock before executing later instructions
    mov   r8d, eax    ; low half of start time.   We ignore the high half in EDX, assuming the time is less than 2^32, i.e. less than about 1 second.

    xor   eax, eax    ; hint = EAX[7:4] = 0 = C1 sleep state
                      ; ECX still 0: no TSC timeout in EBX, no overriding IF to 1
    mwaitx  eax, ecx

    rdtscp            ; EAX = low half of end time, EDX = high, ECX = core #
    sub     eax, r8d  ; retval = end - start
    ret
```

(LFENCE serializes execution on AMD CPUs if the OS has enabled the Spectre mitigation feature bit, giving lfence that guarantee like on Intel CPUs.  Otherwise it's a NOP on AMD, IIRC.)

Comment: So in other words, mwaitx is pretty much pointless in user mode?

Comment: @Badasahog: huh?  It's useful as an alternative to a *short* spin-wait loop, which is all you ever want to do anyway before sleeping and letting the OS wake you up when the lock is available or the memory changes or whatever (e.g. Linux `futex`).  If you want to keep spinning longer in user-space, call it in a loop that checks the re-arms the monitor (and then re-checks the memory for the value you're waiting for, so you don't miss it.)  This is still occupying a whole hardware thread doing nothing, from the OS's perspective exactly like a spin loop.

Comment: How do I ask the os to wake the thread when the memory changes? My goal here is to find pages that need to be reuploaded to a server or gpu or whatever (this is more of an abstract project than a practical one).

Comment: @Badasahog: Dedicating a whole hardware thread (CPU core) to just waiting for something else to change memory seems like a waste of a core, and you'd miss updates if one happened while you were busy uploading a page and not yet monitoring for another change.  The use-case for `mwaitx` is for lock-free algorithms and spinlocks where one core is waiting for another to change a specific memory location it knows about.  To ask the OS to help *with that* (not your problem), use Linux's [`futex` system call](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/futex.2.html), for example.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm a Windows guy, but I believe there's something along those lines available for me too

Comment: @Badasahog: As they say, there are 2 hard problems in computer science: Cache invalidation and naming things.  This is the first.  Probably you need every write to mark the page as "dirty" in some data structure.  Or if you can write some kernel code, hardware already supports this via the "dirty" bit on the page-table entry.  So you could scan the process's page table (or the region of it where your array is allocated) and look for "dirty" pages; mark them as clean then upload.

Comment: Of course, the kernel already uses the dirty bit to handle paging to disk or memory-mapped files, so this idea would require hooking into that for a specific process.  But there *is* hardware support for recording regions of memory that have been written to, in an easy-to-scan-for way.  I don't expect it to be easy to take advantage of, and maybe not even practical on a normal Windows or Linux system; even a Linux kernel *module* might not be able to modify the necessary code, so it might require a customized kernel build with some new system calls, if this isn't already exposed somehow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242361/discussion-between-badasahog-and-peter-cordes).